# mysql query: group by column

Tags: mysql, database, group-by, sql-order-by

i got this DB:

```
| id      | sl_address  | sl_type      | 
|---------|-------------|--------------|
|       1 |   Street 1  |    GDS       |
|       2 |   Place 3   |    Standard  |
|       3 |   Highway 9 |    Excellent |
|       4 |   Street 2  |    Excellent |
|       5 |   Square 3  |    GDS       |
|       6 |   Plaza 7   |    Standard  |
|       7 |   Street 3  |    Excellent |
```

I'd like to show results group by sl_type but not in alphabetical order (Standard, GDS, Excellent).

Comment: What would the desired result look like?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [field function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field)

```
SELECT *
FROM SomeTable
ORDER BY FIELD(sl_type, 'Standard', 'GDS', 'Excellent')
```

Note that doing it like this will mean that a value of sl_type not in that list will be sorted to the first position